# Maven: project compiles without dependency defined in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that I tried building in two different ways:

- With `-Dmaven.repo.local` set to a brand new directory created just for the build.
- Without `-Dmaven.repo.local` (then I assume it defaults to `~/.m2`

I'm finding it very weird that my project compiles just fine when I am NOT using `-Dmaven.repo.local`, even though ***some dependencies are not in the POM***. The log does NOT show these dependencies being downloaded or resolved from the local repo (`~/.m2`).

If I try to build specifying a brand new local repository, the build fails because javac can't resolve some classes (meaning Maven and Java don't know where these dependencies are).

```
[ERROR] /home/jenkins1/slave_home/workspace/Build/2.x/Dev_Test/2-Mainline_Stream_official_Green_build_V2/workspace/com.mycompany.myproj.iaas.rest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproj/iaas/api/rest/MigrationUninstallModulesResource.java:[18,23] error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[ERROR] /home/jenkins1/slave_home/workspace/Build/2.x/Dev_Test/2-Mainline_Stream_official_Green_build_V2/workspace/com.mycompany.myproj.iaas.rest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproj/iaas/api/rest/MigrationUninstallModulesResource.java:[42,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Path
[ERROR] /home/jenkins1/slave_home/workspace/Build/2.x/Dev_Test/2-Mainline_Stream_official_Green_build_V2/workspace/com.mycompany.myproj.iaas.rest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproj/iaas/api/rest/assets/MigrationUninstallModulesAsset.java:[16,18] error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[ERROR] /home/jenkins1/slave_home/workspace/Build/2.x/Dev_Test/2-Mainline_Stream_official_Green_build_V2/workspace/com.mycompany.myproj.iaas.rest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproj/iaas/api/rest/assets/MigrationUninstallModulesAsset.java:[17,23] error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[ERROR] /home/jenkins1/slave_home/workspace/Build/2.x/Dev_Test/2-Mainline_Stream_official_Green_build_V2/workspace/com.mycompany.myproj.iaas.rest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproj/iaas/api/rest/assets/MigrationUninstallModulesAsset.java:[19,41] error: package org.apache.wink.common.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /home/jenkins1/slave_home/workspace/Build/2.x/Dev_Test/2-Mainline_Stream_official_Green_build_V2/workspace/com.mycompany.myproj.iaas.rest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproj/iaas/api/rest/assets/MigrationUninstallModulesAsset.java:[23,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Asset
[ERROR] /home/jenkins1/slave_home/workspace/Build/2.x/Dev_Test/2-Mainline_Stream_official_Green_build_V2/workspace/com.mycompany.myproj.iaas.rest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproj/iaas/api/rest/assets/TeamAsset.java:[12,18] error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

As you can see, the build fails to find `javax.ws.rs`, which is expected since the dependency is NOT in the POM. What I don't understand is why the build succeeds when I suppress the `-Dmaven.local.repo`.

The POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.myproj.iaas</groupId>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../com.mycompany.myproj.iaas</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.myproj.iaas</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myproj myproj-RestAPI.war</name>
    <url>http://www.mycompany.com</url>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.myproj.iaas</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.myproj.iaas</groupId>
            <artifactId>bpm</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.myproj.iaas</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${version.logback}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-json4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ripe.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-ip-math</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
            <version>10.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}.${buildLabel}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <description>This component builds the myproj-RestAPI.war file.</description>
</project>
```

It is very confusing - if the dependency is not defined in the POM, how is it being resolved?

Comment: Unclear, are those transitive dependencies of things declared in the POM?

Comment: why dont you paste the log on your question?

Comment: @Tunaki the dependencies are not declared in the POM. It's in the question description :)

Comment: @thiagoh Done..

Comment: good start @Phil now could you please add the pom.xml?

Comment: @Phil You do have dependencies declared in the POM, I don't understand your comment saying there aren't?

Comment: The failing dependencies are not in the POM (e.g. `javax.ws.rs:jsr311`), but the build succeeds when I don't set `maven.local.repo`. I want to understand how the build can succeed without the dependencies in the pom.

Comment: Because they are [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)?

Comment: Shouldn't the transitive dependencies be downloaded into the specified repo along with the explicit ones?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the Maven log show these transitive dependencies being downloaded? (for the case when the build succeeds)

Comment: @Tunaki I understand your point about transitive dependencies. What I don't understand is why Maven will treat transitive dependencies differently when `-Dmaven.local.repo` is provided.

Comment: It won't, so it's really unclear what behaviour you're asking about here. You should simplify your POM to a couple of dependencies only, start small, and state explicitly what's getting downloaded or not downloaded and what is troubling you...

Comment: Also, I ran `mvn dependency:tree` and found out that the failing dependency is not a transitive dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely missed a part of Maven log when it tries to resolve all dependencies. 
Your log shows that it is a Compiler errors not Maven.

It always goes that way:

1. Maven resolves all dependencies including transitive ones (if they are not excluded)
2. For those dependencies Maven cannot find in local repo and cannot dowload from remote repos there is a warning about it. (you missed it).
   Also Maven may not try to download them again for some period of time - it depends on remote repo settings). Maven puts some "empty decoy" into local repo for missing dependencies.
3. Maven still going to Compiler with all available jars in Classpath
   just because if jar defined as dependency it does not mean that it is needed and code may compiles.
4. Finally you got your Errors from Compiler because code actually uses some classes from some dependencies
   That's it.

BTW: I do not understand completely the purpose of that exercise...

Comment: My purpose is not to understand why the build fails in one of the cases, but why and how it works well in the other case. In one of the scenarios the build completes just fine, even though the dependency is not in the POM, is not a transitive dependency and the log doesn't ever show it being downloaded.

Comment: Your failing dependency `javax.ws.rs` must be there in the tree if you use REST in the code. You just missed it.

Comment: well it's not in the tree :)